com.google.api.gax.rpc.FailedPreconditionException: This method is not supported for this subscription type
com.google.api.gax.rpc.FailedPreconditionException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.FailedPreconditionException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: FAILED_PRECONDITION: This method is not supported for this subscription type.
at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:102) ~[gax-2.19.4.jar!/:2.19.4]
at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:41) ~[gax-2.19.4.jar!/:2.19.4]
at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.StreamingSubscriberConnection$1.onFailure(StreamingSubscriberConnection.java:331) ~[google-cloud-pubsub-1.120.24.jar!/:1.120.24]
at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:67) ~[api-common-2.2.1.jar!/:?]
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1132) ~[guava-31.1-jre.jar!/:?]
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:31) ~[guava-31.1-jre.jar!/:?]
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1270) ~[guava-31.1-jre.jar!/:?]
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:1038) ~[guava-31.1-jre.jar!/:?]
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:808) ~[guava-31.1-jre.jar!/:?]
at com.google.api.core.AbstractApiFuture$InternalSettableFuture.setException(AbstractApiFuture.java:94) ~[api-common-2.2.1.jar!/:?]
at com.google.api.core.AbstractApiFuture.setException(AbstractApiFuture.java:76) ~[api-common-2.2.1.jar!/:?]
at com.google.api.core.SettableApiFuture.setException(SettableApiFuture.java:51) ~[api-common-2.2.1.jar!/:?]
at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.StreamingSubscriberConnection$StreamingPullResponseObserver.onError(StreamingSubscriberConnection.java:255) ~[google-cloud-pubsub-
here type of subscription_id corresponding to topicId need to change, either pull to push or vice versa

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I changed the type of subscription_id pull to push or vice versa than Its working. Thanks
I'm using gcp cloud pub-sub message engine.
